# In XML documenttion, how do I reference another class that has the same name in the same namespace?

Tags: c#, .net-core, xml-documentation

I have several C# packages that are closely related to each other. Each one of these has its own `IServiceCollectionsExtensions` static class living in the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace. What I want to do is in the XML comments of one these methods, refer to a method in the other class in the other assembly. Example:

```
// assembly Foo
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
{
    public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>This is some info</summary>
        public static IServiceCollection AddFoo(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // register some types in the DI container
            return services;
        }
    }
}

// assembly Foo.Bar, which has a dependency on Foo
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
{
    public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// You don't need to call <see cref="IServiceCollectionsExtensions.AddFoo(IServiceCollection)" /> -- we'll do it for you
        /// </summary>
        public static IServiceCollection AddFooBar(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddFoo();
            // register some other types in the DI container
            return services;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in the Foo.Bar project, Visual Studio complains that "XML has cref attribute 'AddFoo(IServiceCollection)' that could not be resolved" (CS1574).

Note that this is a contrived example. I'm perfectly aware that you can register the same services multiple times in most cases.

How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer might be "don't do that", and just name your extension method classes different names. If they're extension methods after all, the name of the class usually doesn't matter. (Defining stuff inside the "Microsoft" namespace is also a bit confusing here, since well, you're not shipping this in a Microsoft assembly, I'm guessing!)

If you really want to do that, in a cref you can start your name with T: to reference a type explicitly or M: to reference a method explicitly, but at that point you opt out of all validation or IDE features since that's the backdoor.

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking that might be the case, but I thought I'd put it out there in case there was a solution. I did want to put all of the into the Microsoft namespace, though, because I wanted consumers of the packages to just install them without having to add a bunch of `using` statements. This is apparently standard practice for a lot of packages (e.g., AWS). I suppose using different class names is the way to go.

Comment: It's a common practice to put DI registration extension methods in that namespace so you don't have to add yet another `using` directive to Program.cs / Startup.cs. It's a narrow case (only the stuff needed for startup). They're not going to be used anywhere else and it lowers the bar to discovery when getting started with a library. However, those libraries do name the class with something specific to the library, so although they're polluting the namespace, they're making a reasonable attempt to avoid collisions.

Comment: @howcheng: Put just the DI-related stuff there. Generally. your assembly should have its own namespace for its purposes. I would advise against putting everything in another vendor's namespace, except (maybe) if it's a few extension methods that provide new overloads of existing methods, or something like that. Be a good citizen, don't make broad assumptions on behalf of the consumer of your library. Let them not opt in when they don't want it.

Comment: @madreflection Oh yeah, it's only the IServiceCollection and IConfigurationBuilder extensions that will be living in the MSFT namespaces. Everything else in that package will be our custom ones.

Comment: OK, good. You said you *"I did want to put all of the[m] into the Microsoft namespace"* but it was unclear that "them" was just the extension method classes and not the entirety of the types in your library, so I had to say something just in case.